# Change Table Headers On URL Variable String

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a website table that shows a variety of data, which currently changes which data are viewed based on a variable string passed in the URL. This example looks as follows:

```
www.acoolwebsite.com/?variable=var1
```

I've provided a synthesized view of the table's current header structure, which is as follows:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Static1</th>
        <th>Static2</th>
        <th>Static3</th>
        <th>Variable1</th>
        <th>Variable2</th>
        <th>Variable3</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am looking to change the headers `Variable1`, `Variable2`, & `Variable3` to another set of headers, say `Change1`, `Change2`, & `Change3` if the passed variable in the URL `www.acoolwebsite.com/?variable=var1` matches a certain string.

Using JavaScript, I've been able to partition the variable passed in the URL, but am uncertain how to isolate and alter header names. What additional steps can I take to produce this outcome?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an ID for your table headers and use `innerHTML`. See sample snippet below:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Static1</th>
        <th>Static2</th>
        <th>Static3</th>
        <th id="v1">Variable1</th>
        <th id="v2">Variable2</th>
        <th id="v3">Variable3</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="changeHeaders()" />
<script>
function changeHeaders() {
  // You variables
  let v1 = 'change1';
  let v2 = 'change2';
  let v3 = 'change3';
  document.getElementById("v1").innerHTML = v1;
  document.getElementById("v2").innerHTML = v2;
  document.getElementById("v3").innerHTML = v2;
}
</script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```